# Dropdown list displaying [object object] instead of value from sql table

Tags: sql, knockout.js, drop-down-menu

my dropdown list is returning [object][object] instead of the value. I am getting the values from an sql table. Any assistance would be great. Thanks in advance.

viewmodel

```
 vm.addObservables('selected');
vm.addObservableArrays('list');

_Integration.GetAll('sqlTable').then(function(vals){
        vm.list(vals);

});
```

html

```
<select id="dropDown" name="dropDown" 
    data-bind='options: list, 
               value: selected, 
               optionsCaption: "Choose...", 
               autoSave: true'>

</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're binding the dropdown to an array of objects without saying how to interpret those objects. Add the data-bind optionsText: 'fieldName' where fieldName is the name of the property on your object that you'd like to display.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

sample:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                   optionsText: 'countryName',
                   value: selectedCountry,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```